# How to roll back hardware updates?

Tags: updates, hardware, update-manager

I just did the hardware updates available through the update manager, this is the first time I had ever seen or heard of a hardware update but I figured it would be legit because it was coming from the official Ubuntu update manager. It mentioned something about being one of the last updates before support was dropped so I thought it would be a good idea but now I think either my resolution or driver has messed up because the quality of graphics and everything things else is poor now. It's not terrible, but I feel like it was better looking before the updates. anyone know a solution?

Comment: What is a hardware update?

Comment: I believe he is talking about updating the Hardware Enablement Stack: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I clicked the cog and then clicked software up to date, and when the update manager popped up, just below where it says the software on the computer is up to date on the upper left side, there was a clickable link of some sort mentioning a hardware update. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack, and yes I think this is it.

Comment: The hardware update should also be a new kernel; so use the older one.

Comment: @Rinzwind, how would I re-install or roll back to the old kernel?

Comment: You do not. You choose the kernel during boot in Grub.

Comment: @Rinzwind, That worked thank you, I never knew you could do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go back to a previous version of the kernel and updates, when first booting up, select previous linux versions from the GRUB menu and choose the version you want to boot up with.